# Can we delete the "nod" tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There is [nod](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nod); I think this was created by mistake.

Is it possible to delete it, so that it doesn't get misused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged "nod" and "node", not as a synonym, effectively deleting it.